# How to give reference to existing web service in xamarin forms pcl

Tags: visual-studio, rest, xamarin.forms

I am using visual studio 2013.

I am trying to create a mobile app with the Xamarin Forms with my existing web service which is created for web application,when i tried to create a service reference in pcl (portable lib) there i cannot find the **Add -> Web reference** option.

So i created a new project in my solution with the existing pcl project Add a web reference there and started my coding then gave reference to that project in my (Android,IOS,Windows).

**Structure:**
[image]

Now my ClassLibrary1 which acts as common lib for cross-platform where i have my web service part.

**From Android To ClassLibrary1:**

```cs
namespace App1.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            try
            {
                Class1 a = new Class1();
                string data = a.Login();
            }
```

**ClassLibrary1:**

```cs
public class Class1
{       
    public void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLibrary1.Reference.Service service = new ClassLibrary1.Reference.Service();
            ClassLibrary1.Reference.Response response = service.login("xxxx", "yyyy");
        }
```

I used to access my ClassLibrary1 from my various platfrom for service.
Now when calling that project from my (Android,IOS,Windows) it gives me error as below:

**The class System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase could not be loaded, used in System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089**

Tried by changing the **version =2.0.0.0** but no use actually this version refers from System.dll but there i cannot find anything generated in my dll it is empty.

How can i solve this can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Why don't you reference the web service by the url?

Comment: @ Mario Galván i tried it by url in service reference but there i didn't get the methods generated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly are you using HttpClient?
`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`
`HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(your_url, cancellationToken);`

Comment: if load service from my android shows error as Could not load file or assembly 'XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in my XXX project

Comment: let edit my question for ur clear understanding

Comment: if i call my service from android project

Comment: @ Mario Galván i have edited my question my u plz see it and help me

Comment: @Mario Galván i have edited my question my u plz see it.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do what you want with Xamarin forms, please refer to this document http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/ it may help you.